# PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka - Scaling Consumers for multiple topics with different loads

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

We subscribed to **7 topics** with `spark.readStream` in **1 single** running **spark app**.
After transforming the event payloads, we save them with `spark.writeStream` to our database.

For one of the topics, the data is inserted only batch-wise (once a day) with a very high load. This delays our reading from *all* other topics, too. For example ([grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPFKY.jpg)), the delay between a produced and consumed record over all topics stays below 1m the whole day. When the bulk-topic receives its events, our **delay increases up to 2 hours on *all* (!) topics**.

1. How can we solve this? we already tried 2 successive readStreams (the bulk-topic separately), but it didn't help.
   Further info: We use 6 executors, 2 executor-cores. The topics have a different number of partitions (3 to 30). Structured Streaming Kafka Integration v0.10.0.
2. General question: How can we scale the consumers in spark structured streaming? Is 1 readStream equal to 1 consumer? or 1 executor? or what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution for our problem: 
Our [grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp37o.jpg) after the change shows, that the batch-data topic still peaks but without blocking the consumption on other topics.

What we did: 
We still have 1 spark app. We used 2 successive spark.readStreams but also added a sink for each.

In code:

```
priority_topic_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka')
     .options(..).option('subscribe', ','.join([T1, T2, T3])).load()
bulk_topic_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka')
     .options(..).option('subscribe', BULK_TOPIC).load()

priority_topic_stream.writeStream.foreachBatch(..).trigger(..).start()
bulk_topic_stream.writeStream.foreachBatch(..).trigger(..).start()
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

To minimize the peak on the bulk-stream we will try out increasing its partitions like adviced from @partlov. But that would have only speeded up the consumption on the bulk-stream but not resolved the issue from blocking our reads from the priority-topics.

Answer (score 1):

1. Partitions are main source of parallelism in Kafka so I suggest you increase number of partitions (at least for topic which has performance issues). Also you may tweak some of consumer caching options mentioned in [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#consumer-caching). Try to keep number of partitions 2^n. At the end you may increase size of driver machine if possible.
2. I'm not completely sure, but I think Spark will try to keep same number of consumer as number of partitions per topic. Also I think that actually stream is fetched from Spark driver always (not from workers).